# swift framework inside a framework , search path not found error

Tags: swift, search, path, frameworks

I am getting a crash while running an application with a framework inside another framework.

here is the error message.

> '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/temp/Build/Products/Debug/frameworkTest.app/Contents/Frameworks/myFramework.framework/Versions/A/../Frameworks/innerFramework.framework/Versions/A/innerFramework'
> (no such file)

Inside **frameworkTest.app** there is a framework named **myFramework.framework** and inside that framework there is another framework named **innerFramework.framework**

the **myFramework.framework** is present in the application's Framework folder, and **innerFramework.framework** is present inside the **myFramework.framework** 's Framework folder.

when we check the above path with finder, it finds the frameworks but app search path is not finding the file.

These are the Framework search path for the application

```
$(inherited)
 $(PROJECT_DIR)/frameworkTest
```

the Framework search path for the application

```
$(inherited)
$(PROJECT_DIR)/myFramework/Frameworks
$(PROJECT_DIR)/myFramework/Frameworks/innerFramework
```

default was non recursive and tried recursive also.

Could any one suggest a way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, tried with clearing framework search paths and it worked for me. The framework inside another framework was recognised. Not the best solution, but as long as it works... :)

It won't work if you have binary framework in binary framework.